# How to change one of the ribbontext value in other acitvity?

Tags: javascript, android

Description: In my `mainActivity` class I have added one header and ribbon with text and send it to other `secondActivity` class to add some more rows (by setting `onclick` listeners) by using `addRow(rootLayout, length,buttonHeight)`. My requirement is, If we click on any of the row which we added in `secondActivity` class, I have to change the ribbon text which we added in the `mainActivity` class.

Could any one please help out of this?

```
        code:
        MainActivity.java
        -----------------
    /*Main Activity Class which consists ribbon text and called method for creating the second row*/
        public class MainActivity extends Acitvity{ 

           public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){    
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
                 setContentView(R.layout.mainView);     **//Main view**  
                 final FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById    (R.id.mainViewRootLayout);    
                 FrameLayout ribbonLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayout);    
                 TextView ribbonText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayoutText);    
                 ribbonText.setText("MainRibbonViewBeforeClick");  

                 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService     (context.Layout_Inflater_service);   

                addRow(rootLayout);  
         }  
        }

/*Here is the calling method in same class which adds one more text view, if we click on text view the ribbon text of oncreate method has to be changed*/  

  public void addRow(FrameLayout rootLayout)
       {
      Rect rect = new Rect();
      rootLayout.getDrawingRect(rect);
      FrameLayout ribbonLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.subRibbonLayout);
      TextView subText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subribbonLayoutText);
      subText.setText("ClicktoChangeTheRibbon");
      subText.setOnclickListener(new onClickListener()  **//Setting up the listener 
     {   
     public vid onclick(View v){     

              /*Here I need to implement a code that changes the ribbon text which I have added in onCreate method*/  
                 }  
            });  
          }
```

}

Please have a look on the above code and suggest me the solution.

Comment: So your ribbon text was an textview?? :) Good that you have posted your code...Are you saying that on the onClick event you need to show the mainactivity's textview widget.text property to some other value??

Comment: Just pass the textview object "ribbonText" to the secondActivity and assign the value to the textview object "ribbonText"

Comment: Thanks Mothy.... It is working now. Your suggestion is really appreciated. I am new to this android :( but want to learn by taking help like this..

Comment: Could you please give me suggestion to my next question too?

Comment: Glad that i could help you :) Please accept the answer so that it will be helpful to others too

Comment: Hi Mothy, I have added the question.. Could you please suggest me the solution?                                                               Question is: While I am trying to add nested linearLayout under existing linear layout, application is saying “applicaton has stopped, force closing”

Answer (score 0):

Create a static variable assign the text value of the ribbon to it.On the clickevent of any rows in the secondActivity class change the value of the variable to the value you want to display for the ribbon text.

Comment: Hi Mothy, Thanks for your help. I am new to this android, could you please explain me more precisely... Following my pseudo code.

Comment: Can any one please look on my above code and suggest me the solution?

Comment: public static string ribbonText=FirstRibbonText.ToString(); and in the second activity button click,change the FirstActivity.ribbonText="newStringText";

Comment: Mothy your work would be appreciated.I am done the same as per your suggestion... But still the value is not effecting the ribbon.. Could you please implement in the code which I have provide above?

Comment: Hi Mothy... i have modifiied the code above.. please have a look on it... My actual code is different desktop. that's why I couldn't able to copy the same code.. Pleae explain me with a simple example as above... That would be very helpful to me.. Thanks in advance